# How to detect memory safety errors in a linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, drivers, memory, kernel-modules

For the past week, I was working on a simplistic kernel module that creates a character device driver that allows the passing of messages between user and kernel space.

All good and nice, I found KEDR (https://github.com/euspectre/kedr) and I can now detect memory leaks.

However, the question stands: Is there a way to detect **out of bounds accesses** and any other errors such as **Uninitialized Memory** etc?  In userspace programs, we might sometimes see a **segfault**, or we can use **valgrind** to try and detect most of these errors.

I tried to artificially write out of the bounds of an array and the OS does not complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KASAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.3/dev-tools/kasan.html) is a close equivalent to `memcheck`, which is what you mean when you say `valgrind`.

It is [The kernel address sanitizer](https://lwn.net/Articles/612153/) [LWN.net 2014].  See also [Software-tag-based KASAN](https://lwn.net/Articles/766768/) [LWN.net 2018].